# find inside a hash mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this struct in my collection:

```
{foo : 1, bar : 4, baz : {a : 1, b : 2 ,c : "fafofu"}}
```

How do I find "a" and "b" inside baz ?
It does not works `db.my_collection.find({baz : {a : 1, b : 2});`

I don't care about if "c" is "fafofu" or "cacocu" does not matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `.` to reach into the baz object.

```
db.my_collection.find({"baz.a" : 1, "baz.b" : 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you try the following

```
{foo : 1, bar : 4, a: ["1"], b: ["2"],  "c": ["fafofu"]}
```

You could use `find`/`findOne`:

```
print(db.???.findOne( { c: "fafofu" } ).foo);
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo

Unfortunately I don't have the ability to test this.

```
print(db.???.baz.findOne( { c: "fafofu" } ).foo);
```

My problem is how to find the data, becauase if you don't know the key it is difficult to optimize the performance of your search. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I understand that most people in the world are not native English speakers (I am not one, either) but, like it or not, English _is_ the lingua franca of the IT industry. You should consider translating your answer into English so that the rest of us can read it and comment on it.

Comment: All answers should be provided in English here. Fortunately I have been speaking Brazilian Portuguese for about a decade so I was able to translate this for you. I apologize if I didn't carry your meaning over exactly.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Thank you for taking the time to translate this

Comment: I have tried to edit, but I can't edit posts with links yet, because i don't have reputation! I replied in Portuguese because I know the mantovani personally, i just realized that neither was in English!